# using node jsrequest for the flickr API

Tags: node.js

I'm using the node js request function to access the following URL for the flickr API

```
https://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/access_token?oauth_token=X&oauth_verifier=X&oauth_consumer_key=X&oauth_nonce=X&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1468959629921&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=X
```

For some reason, I'm getting a response timeout. What would you recommend that I do to fix this?

Here's the code

```
request(url, function (e, r, body) {
    if (!e && r.statusCode === 200) {
        var tokens = qs.parse(body);
        console.log('test1');
        var key = self.PLATFORM_TYPE + '_' + tokens.user_nsid;
        var user = {
            tokens: tokens,
            key: key,
            platform: self.PLATFORM_TYPE
        };
        deferred.resolve(user);
    } else {
        deferred.reject(body);
    }
});
```